Malformed CDATA in xml
I get a XML from a third-party service,
This one is malformed sometimes CDATA tag aren't close,
My goal is to write a regex capable of catching only malformed CDATA,
example :
<Couleur_regroupement>
   <![CDATA[Rose;Jaune 
</Couleur_regroupement>
<Dessus_Tige>
   <![CDATA[26]]>
</Dessus_Tige>

For now I have this one :

((<{1}[a-zA-Z-]>{1}){1}(<![CDATA[){1}((?!]]>).)((</){1}[a-zA-Z-]*>{1}){1})

Which is working on the first example but not on the second...
It's a false positive if html inside CDATA...
<Desart>
    <![CDATA[Title<br><img src=img.jpg> blabla <i>bla</i>  blabla<br><img src=img.jpg></br>
    ]]>
</Desart>


Surely when you get faulty goods from any supplier, you should send them back for replacement? Otherwise you're just encouraging the supplier to continue to produce shoddy deliverables.

I quite agree with you, unfortunately we work with a company that itself uses an ERP that is far from being well developed, which sends us the XML and is not at all cooperative when it comes to correcting bugs.

Well, you could make progress by asking them to stop referring to it as "XML" when it isn't. That sometimes helps to drive the message home.
